# OracleMTSRecoveryService failed to start?

Tags: .net, oracle, odac

i am getting this error while starting `OracleMTSRecoveryService` :

```
Could not start the OracleMTSRecoveryService service on Local Computer.
Error 1: Incorrect function.*
```

Also during installation of *ODAC service start failed*.

`OracleXETNSListener` is also not starting. i have reinstalled ODAC but problem remains.

any suggestions? Any service conflicts?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Look at the registry value `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Oracle\OracleMTSRecoveryService\Protid_0\` and make sure that the host name matches your machine name.

If you have *Windows 7* the registry path is

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ORACLE\OracleMTSRecoveryService\Protid_0
```

Comment: Please specify for what version of Windows is your solution, because the path is wrong for Windows 7

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me as well, but the registry path was wrong.  I'm running Windows 7 and the Oracle 11gR2 client and the registry path is:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ORACLE\OracleMTSRecoveryService\Protid_0
```

Here is the registry file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ORACLE\OracleMTSRecoveryService\Protid_0]
"Name"="HTTP"
"Host"="putyourmachinesnamehere.com"
"Port"="2030"
```

Answer (score 1):

I have windows 7, i had same problem but the reason of my problem was, i deleted the original oracle folder from C:\app------\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\BIN\omtsreco.exe, so that is why it was failing.

these steps worked for me :)

This worked for me in Windows 7:

1. Open your Registry Editor window running command: regedit
2. Keep error window opened while you change the following registry-key value:

"Computer\hkey_local_machine\system\controlset001\service\OracleMTSRecoveryService".

1. Search for ImagePath Value and change the path to where your Oracle is actually installed. In your case is C:\app\myuser\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\BIN\omtsreco.exe "OracleMTSRecoveryService"

Answer (score 1):

I did open up regedit and the server name was wrong because I was trying to install the Oracle 11g software on a clone copy of our production server. So the hostname was still matching that of the production server. I right clicked on Host and choosed modify then changed the server name to my current(cloned) server name

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and my issue was that the host name was wrong in my *tnsnames* and *listener* folders from *C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\ADMIN*

This happened after a domain migration of my computer as it's name changed.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it helped to set the Oracle installation folder to the PATH environment variable, e.g. to c:\oracle\odac.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in Windows 7:

**1.** Open your Registry Editor window running command: regedit

**2.** Keep error window opened while you change the following registry-key value:

"Computer\hkey_local_machine\system\controlset001\service\OracleMTSRecoveryService".

**3.** Search for ImagePath Value and change the path to where your Oracle is actually installed. In y case is C:\app\myuser\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\BIN\omtsreco.exe "OracleMTSRecoveryService"

**4.** Go back to error window and click in Retry.

And fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

to AndrewB 
Thanks very much - this worked for me.

I also got there using procmon.exe from sysinternals 
filter :

> process=omtsreco.exe
>   then filtered to view only registry entries.... 
>   Had to update the hostname (full computer name of the server) by the new one.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Just changed following registries:

**Step 1. : Update path in registry:**

**`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\system\controlset001\service\OracleMTSRecoveryService`**
 Set appropriate imagepath entry for file **omtsreco.exe**

 In my case it's : `E:\app1\NAL65\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\BIN

**Step 2. : Update host in registry:**

**`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\ORACLE\OracleMTSRecoveryService\Protid_0`**

it may be deffer for you like:
**`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\OracleMTSRecoveryService\Protid_0`**

By default it takes DESKTOP-DESKTOP replace it with original one.

**Step 3: retry**

**That's it !!!**

Answer (score 0):

This issue came up all of a sudden with the service of Oracle12c-32bit (version 12.1.0.2.0). For me the issue turned out to be that the permissions of one or more files/folders under:

C:\oracle\client\\product\12.1.0\client_1

Got changed in a way that was causing the error at hand ('permission denied' as seen on windows event logs). I simply made a recursive change of permissions on C:\oracle effectively granting full-access everywhere under the root folder to all the users and groups that had full access to C:\oracle.

The weird thing about all this is that only the 32bit oracle-service got clogged due to insufficient permissions. My 64bit oracle-service didn't suffer from a similar issue which is weird. I don't know where to attribute the "spontaneous permissions-tweak" that broke the 32bit service. Go figure ...

Answer (score -1):

The OracleMTSRecoveryService couldn't start when I was installed Oracle DB 11g as well, at 71% of installing progress, but after I turned off my antivirus program (Avast Pro 15) and clicked Retry, it worked for me. The AV firewall may be the key problem.

Answer (score -1):

changing the value of Host file from localhost to `127.0.0.1` in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ORACLE\OracleMTSRecoveryService\Protid_0` worked

Also clicking on retry worked for me. After clicking on retry the installation proceeded without any warning or error.